# ObjectDetecionAPI TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, ubuntu-16.04

I did everything it says at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md and lastly updated my protoc. When i enter `$ protoc --version`, it throws libprotoc 3.5.1 on the terminal. But when i try to do `$ python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py`, it throws an error TypeError: _ *new* _() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: All the answers mentioned re-install a newer or an older version of protobuf, but one important thing is to recompile the *.proto files as instructed in the installation guide after the re-installation of protobuf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3995#issuecomment-382261558) in the TensorFlow repository, you should downgrade your protobuf to 3.4.0.

Comment: It works for me! First, download the version of 3.4.0 `https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.4.0/protoc-3.4.0-linux-x86_64.zip`, and then `mv` the command `protoc` to `/usr/local/bin/`, finally `mv` the include directory to `/usr/local/include/`. At the end, recompile your `.proto` file, rerun your code.

Answer (score 29):

Updating protobuf to 3.6 works for me.

```
pip install -U protobuf
```

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3995#issuecomment-400183986

Comment: Worked on Linux for me, not related to the original TensorFlow part of the question but rather when working with pybind11 and protobuf files.

Answer (score 2):

Updating `protobuf` to **3.8** works for me.

```
pip install -U protobuf
```

Answer (score 1):

On python3, none of the above solution worked. So I uninstalled the existing installation using pip. Then installed again by `pip3 install protobuf`. Then it worked.