# Tensorflow Objection_Detection API:TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options', protoc 3.4.0 doesn't work

Tags: python, tensorflow

Similar to this question:[TypeError: **new**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338968/objectdetecionapi-typeerror-new-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-seria)

That question was solved by using `protoc 3.4.0`. However, it doesn't work on my PC. When I run `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py` in cmd with protoc 3.4.0, I still get the error.

Tensorflow version: 1.9.0

OS: Window 10

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by installing a lower version of protoc? 
Also did it compile well while installing?

You can also try the manual protobuf installation suggested on [their GitHub page](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#protobuf-compilation>).

Let me know what works for you.

Comment: I solved it! It's not because of the version of protoc and 3.4.0 works. I referred to a Chinese version of `Installation` initially and I set the `PYTHONPATH` twice in the environment variables, which is the key mistake. Also, my python version is 3.6.6, so I also changed `xrange` in `object_detection\anchor_generators\multiscale_grid_anchor_generator.py", line 61` into `range`. Thx, anyway.

Comment: Right! That makes sense. I fell into those problems too initially. Hope you are having fun with the API! Good luck.